# Trouble getting Virtualenv to Import Numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, import, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv

I am having trouble with all libraries, but let me focus on `numpy`.  If I am outside a virtualenv, I can go into the Python interpreter and do:

```
import numpy
```

and that works. But if I got into a `virtualenv` and try it:

```
$ workon test
(test):~/Project/test$ python

>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

After hours of Googling I believe the problem must be in my understanding of `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`. I have tried the obvious:

```
(test):~/Projects/test$ pip install numpy
```

but I got the error:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

I also tried doing `sudo apt-get install python-dev` but got the errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am running `Python2.7.3` on `Ubuntu 12.04` and have PyDev (no virtualenv) running with a project that currently imports libraries (like `numpy`) with no trouble. I have tried using the Ubuntu Software Center to install `python-dev`, but I get the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

virtualenv by default doesn't let you import packages from the global environment. Use `[mk]virtualenv --system-site-packages` to allow it to import system packages.

`python-dev` is a system package, so the `pip` error is expected. Not sure about the apt error, but you could ask on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) to try to resolve it.

Comment: Sorry for the bother, but when you say 'use `[mk]virtualenv --system-site-packages`', what do you mean? Thanks for the response.

Comment: When you're initially creating the virtualenv, eg with `mkvirtualenv name`, add the `--system-site-packages` argument. Then you can import global packages.

Comment: Just to be clear, does this in any way break the functionality of Virtualenv? Because it seems like the environment is not longer separate from my global environment.

Comment: It's an intended function of virtualenv and doesn't break anything. It just means that, well, anything you have installed in the global env is also available in all your virtualenvs (unless overridden). So you need to be a little careful about what's available globally if you don't want certain packages available or so on.